# loop to remove repeated elements of a vector and add corresponding elements of another vector

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am using MATLAB to write a code that multiplies polynomials. Most parts of my code work however there is one part where I have two row vectors `a` and `b`. I want to remove repeated elements of `a` and then add the corresponding elements of `b`. This is what I have written

```
c=length(a);
d=length(b);
remove=[];
for i=1:c
    for j=i+1:c
        if (a(i)==a(j))
            remove=[remove,i];
            b(j)=b(i)+b(j);
        end
    end
end
a(remove)=[];
b(remove)=[];
```

The problem with this is if there is an element in a that appears more than twice, it doesn't work properly.
For example if `a=[5,6,8,9,6,7,9,10,8,9,11,12]` and `b=[1,7,1,-1,3,21,3,-3,-4,-28,-4,4]`
then once this code is run `a` becomes `[5,6,7,10,8,9,11,12]` which is correct but `b` becomes `[1,10,21,-3,-3,-27,-4,4]` which is correct except the -27 should be a -26.

I know why this happens because the 9 in `a(1,4)` gets compared with the 9 in `a(1,7)` so `b(1,7)` becomes `b(1,7)+b(1,4)` and then `a(1,4)` gets compared with the 9 in `a(1,10)`. and then later the `a(1,7)` compares with `a(1,10)` and so the new `b(1,7)` adds to the `b(1,10)` however the `b(1,4)` adds to the `b(1,10)` too. I somehow need to stop this once one repeated element has been found because here `b(1,4)` has been added twice when it should only be added once.
I am not supposed to use any built in functions, is there a way of resolving this easily?

Comment: Why don't you want to use built in functions? Homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer using built in functions, but assuming you have to stick to your own approach, you can try this:

```
a=[5,6,8,9,6,7,9,10,8,9,11,12];
b=[1,7,1,-1,3,21,3,-3,-4,-28,-4,4];

n = numel(a);
remove = zeros(1,n);

temp = a;
for ii = 1:n
    for jj = ii+1:n
        if temp(ii) == temp(jj)
            temp(ii) = NaN;
            remove(ii) = ii;
            b(jj) = b(jj) + b(ii);

        end
    end
end

a(remove(remove>0)) = []
b(remove(remove>0)) = []

a =
     5     6     7    10     8     9    11    12
b =
     1    10    21    -3    -3   -26    -4     4
```

It's not much different from your approach, except for changing the `ii`th value of `a` if it is found later. To avoid overwriting the values in `a` with `NaN`, I'm using a temporary variable for this.

Also, as you can see, I'm avoiding `remove = [remove i]`, because this will create a growing vector, which is very slow.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you explain what the step
    temp(ii)=NaN;
does please?

Comment: It replaces the `ii`th element of `temp` with `NaN` which is the MATLAB way of represening an element that's Not-a-Number. This way, when you're comparing `temp(ii) == temp(jj)` for the same `ii`, and different `jj`,  you will never get `true` again (which was your problem). Note that `NaN == NaN` returns `False`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved in a vectorized manner with the following indexing nightmare (perhaps someone will come up with a simpler approach):

```
a = [5,6,8,9,6,7,9,10,8,9,11,12];
b = [1,7,1,-1,3,21,3,-3,-4,-28,-4,4];

[sa, ind1] = sort(a);
[~, ii, jj] = unique(sa);
[ind2, ind3] = sort(ind1(ii));
a = a(ind2);
b = accumarray(jj(:),b(ind1)).';
b = b(ind3);
```

---

Anyway, to multiply polynomials you could use [`conv`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/conv.html):

```
>> p1 = [1 3 0 2];                      %// x^3 + 3x^2 + 1
>> p2 = [2 -1 4];                       %// 2x^2 - x + 4
>> conv(p1,p2)
ans =
     2     5     1    16    -2     8    %// 2x^5 + 5x^4 + x^3 + 16x^2 - 2x + 8
```

Comment: I think he is not supposed to use any built-in function.